# React Native Error

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, ecmascript-6

Alguem poderia me ajudar recebi o seguinte feedback

```
Não esqueça de cancelar as notificações e agendar as notificações do dia seguinte quando o usuário terminar um quiz :thumbsup:. Você pode usar, por exemplo, o isQuestionAvaliable para testar. Se não existir mais questões disponíveis, significa que o usuário terminou o quiz, então você executa:

clearLocalNotification()
        .then(setNotification);
```

este é o meu codigo

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

export default class Quiz extends React.Component {

    state = {
        questionIndex: 0,
        correctAnswers: 0,
        shouldShowAnswer: false,
    };

    onCorrect = () => {
        const {questionIndex, correctAnswers} = this.state;
        this.setState({questionIndex: questionIndex + 1, correctAnswers: correctAnswers + 1, shouldShowAnswer: false});
    };

    startQuiz = () => {
        this.setState({questionIndex: 0, correctAnswers: 0, shouldShowAnswer: false});
    };

    backToDeck = () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();

    }

    onIncorrect = () => {
        this.setState({questionIndex: this.state.questionIndex + 1});
    };

    showAnswer = () => {
        this.setState({shouldShowAnswer: !this.state.shouldShowAnswer});
    };

    render() {
        const {questionIndex, correctAnswers, shouldShowAnswer} = this.state;
        const {questions} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        const isQuestionAvailable = questionIndex < questions.length;
        const questionLeft = questions.length - questionIndex;

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                {isQuestionAvailable ?  (
                    <View style={styles.container}>

                        <View style={[styles.group, {justifyContent: 'flex-start', flex: 1}]}>
                            <View>
                                <Text>{questionLeft} / {questions.length}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <View style={[styles.group, {flex: 4}]}>
                            <View>
                                {shouldShowAnswer ? (
                                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                        <Text style={{fontSize: 36}}>{questions[questionIndex].answer}</Text>

                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAnswer}>
                                            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#70dd2f'}}>Question</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>

                                    </View>) : (
                                    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                        <Text style={{fontSize: 36}}>{questions[questionIndex].question}</Text>

                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showAnswer}>
                                            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#ff463f'}}>Answer</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>

                                    </View>
                                )}
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around', flex: 2}}>
                            <View style={styles.container}>

                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onCorrect}>
                                    <Text style={{
                                        backgroundColor: '#70dd2f',
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                        height: 30,
                                        textAlign: 'center',
                                        width: 200
                                    }}>Correct</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onIncorrect}>
                                    <Text style={{
                                        backgroundColor: '#ff463f',
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                        height: 30,
                                        textAlign: 'center',
                                        width: 200,
                                        marginTop: 20
                                    }}>Incorrect</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                            </View>

                        </View>

                    </View>

                ) : (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Text>Score: {correctAnswers}</Text>

                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around', flex: 2}}>
                            <View style={styles.container}>

                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.startQuiz}>
                                    <Text style={{
                                        backgroundColor: '#70dd2f',
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                        height: 30,
                                        textAlign: 'center',
                                        width: 200
                                    }}>Start Quiz</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.backToDeck}>
                                    <Text style={{
                                        backgroundColor: '#ff463f',
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                        height: 30,
                                        textAlign: 'center',
                                        width: 200,
                                        marginTop: 20
                                    }}>Back to Deck</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                            </View>

                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 20,
    }
});
```

A questão é aonde eu coloco esse clearLocalNotification() poderiam me ajudar a resolver este problema

Comment: A linha `{isQuestionAvailable ?  ...` dentro de `render()` é uma condição, se for verdadeira exibe a questão caso contrário exibe o score, então esse é o ponto que deve colocar. Faça o teste.

Comment: Não entendi poderia me explicar um pouco mais detalhado pf

Comment: A condição para verificar se tem questões disponível é `isQuestionAvailable = questionIndex < questions.length` .. na linha 43 você esta verificando se `isQuestionAvailable` é `true` caso seja, irá executar o código das linhas 44~103. Caso seja `false` é porque o usuário terminou o quiz, então irá executar o código das linhas 105~135 e é aqui que você coloca `clearLocalNotification().then(setNotification);`

Comment: entoão no caso ficaria assim `                    </View>

                ) :   clearLocalNotification()
                .then(setNotification)
                (
                    
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Text>Score: {correctAnswers}</Text>

                        <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around', flex: 2}}>
                            <View style={styles.container}>`

Comment: Você deve colocar abaixo da linha 104

Comment: após os : correto fiz isso e da erro de variable

Comment: ReferenceError: Can''t find variable clearLocalNotification

Comment: Para poder ajudar corretamente, você terá que criar um [mcve] para assim poder ajudar a solucionar, também precisamos saber quais bibliotecas esta a utilizando junto ao *React Native*.

Comment: https://github.com/filipenickel/mobile-flashcards